# "window" is not defined with FB call API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a little google apps script to get some data from the Facebook Insight API. It's a total unfamiliar ground for me so I'm trying to build this step by step.

Until now I've only wrote the following script, I know it doesn't return anything but at last it should work so I can start asking for data :

```
function myFuntion() {  

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'My_appid',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

}
```

when I'm running this, I've the following error `"window" is not defined.`. What does it mean ? what do I have this error ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454979/use-the-facebook-api-in-a-google-apps-script-web-app/23300702#23300702)*

`window` is a reference to the browser window: This code snippet is intended more for use in a browser than in an Apps Script sample.

To make use of the API within Apps Script, you'll want to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to make requests.

The [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started/v2.8) shows examples for Curl which could be translated to the UrlFetchApp requests you need to make.

You'll need to [generate an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), which you'll need to include with the requests.

Comment: I've been reading multiple time the question you've mentioned but couldn't really understand.But your answer is really clear thank a lot.